# Drop Down Menu In Navigation Bar got Hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Within the existing navigation bar menu, I want to add and drop down menu on the last menu item. However, by clicking on drop down menu, the menu got hidden be hide html body which looks something like this:

[image]

The drop down menu is on Action menu, and it is hidden already when I clicked on it.

Here I what I tried to do:

```css
html,
body {
  background: #f7f7f8
}

.text-white {
  color: #fff !important;
}

section.header {
  padding: 90px 0;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  float: left;
  margin: 0 46px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  /*display: flex;*/
  background: #099cec;
  height: 64px;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 40px;
  ;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {
  .logo {
    /*position: fixed;*/
    color: #FFF;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #000;
  }
  nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
  }
  .showing {
    max-height: 34em;
  }
  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
}

  .form-group {
      position: relative;
  }
  .form-control {
    background: #f7f7f8;
    border: 0;
  }
  .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
    top: 10px;
  }
  .form-control-feedback {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      display: block;
      width: 2.375rem;
      height: 2.375rem;
      line-height: 2.375rem;
      text-align: center;
      pointer-events: none;
      color: #aaa;
      top: 0;
      left: auto;
      right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="menu-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <!-- <img src="mktlogo.jpg"> -->
      <a href="/Morakot/Package" style="color: #FFF;">Morakot Package</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find a package">
            <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback" style=""></span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/Morakot/Upload">Upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Morakot/CopyToken">Copy Token</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li>
          <!-- Single button -->
          <div class="btn-group dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What am I missing with my style sheet to make my drop down menu work properly ? Thanks

Comment: Please check what you wrote, it's very confusing. Not correct English.

Comment: make sure z-Index of underlying element has less value than that navigation dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the dropdown menu to overlap main menu you can add this css

```
.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```